# Installing iulib - config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in

Tags: macos, configure

I'm trying to install iulib on a Os X 10.5 but when I run the ./configure command it returns the following error:

config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in

I've also tried to run ./build but it returns:

configure.ac:8: version mismatch.  This is Automake 1.10

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
automake --add-missing
```

or just

```
automake
```

It should create your Makefile.in.